# tester for HID devices

Tags: usb, windows-7-x64, hid

I have built my own USB HID device. I want to check, if it is working correctly.

I want to check the descriptors sent by the device, display input reports and send output reports. What tools are capable of this task and runs on Windows 7 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

On a day-to-day basis I use [USBlyzer](http://www.usblyzer.com/). It works well on Windows 7 64-bit.

As far as free tools go, the Windows DDK includes (in C:\winddk\7600.16385.1\tools\avstream\amd64) a tool called UVCview.exe ("USB device viewer") that shows at least some descriptor information.

You might also try [Wireshark](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB), but I admit, I only use it for network and can't speak to the quality of its USB capture.

Comment: Wireshark works with USB on Linux, but no chance for capture on Windows.

Comment: wireshark now has support for USB analysis on windows. pcap is included in install.

Answer (score 2):

(even though it's an old post) -  here is a convenient and free solution:

Our Docklight Scripting software can [test custom USB HID devices](https://docklight.de/dl_faq040/) in the free (evaluation) download already, no time limit. Tested both on Windows 7 and [Windows 10](https://docklightnews.blogspot.com/2016/06/usb-hid-and-windows-10.html). You can access your device via the chosen VID and PID, display input report data and send output reports, even with variable output report ids.